# Can't simulate a click event with javascript in "web application"

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, click

I have searched a lot of information about this but have not found the solution yet.

My problem is the following, I am creating an extension to speed up the movement through several web pages, I have managed it with many of them, but I have come to some where I cannot simulate a click with Javascript and I don't know how to do it.

One of the pages is this: https://sports.betway.es/es/sports/in-play The page is in Spanish domain, therefore I do not know if they can access it from another country (without vpn), although I think that with domain ".com" it works.

The code is as follows, it's pretty simple.

```
var deportesActivos = document.getElementsByClassName("categoryListItemWrapper contentSelectorItemButton")
for(let i=0;i<deportesActivos.length;i++){
    let nombre = deportesActivos[i].lastChild.firstChild.innerText
    if(nombre == data.deporte){
        deportesActivos[i].click()
    }
}
```

`deportesActivos` I collect the DIV elements with that class from the page.
`deportesActivos[i].lastChild.firstChild.innerText` I extract the text of each element

```
if(nombre == data.deporte){
  deportesActivos[i].click()
}
```

When it matches, click to enter the link.

The problem is that the click does not simulate me.
I have bought exactly the element that you click on, I have clicked manually and it works, I have tried to click on other elements of the web page and it does not work, I have tried to give a "listener on click" to the element and it does not work either.
The HTML of the page is as follows:[Image with HTML Code of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr7gL.png)

**I don't know if this helps but on website build with Ionic app neither works**
[image]

Comment: window.open(deportesActivos[i].parentElement.href), when you click those divs, you are going to the href link in their parents

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event does not fully simulate a user click. It just fires the `onClick` handler on the element that you are targeting (and any parents).

If your are just redirecting to a new URL when the button is clicked, you could just do that in your loop instead.

```
// get the links, not the buttons
var deportesActivos = document.getElementsByClassName("categoryListItemWrapper contentSelector");

for (let i=0; i < deportesActivos.length; i++) {
    // Drill down one extralevel to get the button text
    let nombre = deportesActivos[i].firstChild.lastChild.firstChild.innerText;
    if (nombre === data.deporte) {
        // Redirect to the href in the link        
        window.location.href = deportesActivos[i].href;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this website particularly you'r solution will work, but what if I can't catch the url? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Unsure of this use-case. You have to have a URL somewhere to redirect to and it could be the `href` of a `<a>` tag, a data attribute on your button (e.g. `data-href="http://..."`), or a URL stored in JavaScript in some way (among other possibilities).

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: this should work when I try to redirect, but it dosen't when I try to display some hidden content like this: https://imgur.com/a/pKEyIFh, code -> https://imgur.com/a/DYkA7Re

Comment: Since your accordians are likely driven by JavaScript, it seems like triggering the onClick might work. If not, you could probably just directly change the value of "collapsed" to false.

Comment: @ Ed Lucas I've tried this one, but the problem is the data will not update if I change the class data.